# How to make input type's value into decimal using php

Tags: php, input, decimal

I wanted to make the amount entered by the user to be in decimal.

I have tried using this code:

```
$amount = '0.'.$_POST['amount'];
```

Will this work?

I also tried using:

```
$amount = decbin($amount);
```

But it only moved 2 decimal places to the left.

Comment: `Will this work?`. The best way is just test it :)

Comment: Yes it did work but I don't know if the value had turn into decimal or just added "0." in front of it and it is still the value itself. Are there any ways in the value entered into decimal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $format_number = number_format($amount, $no_of_zero_after_decimal_point, '.', '');
```

For Example:

echo $format_number = number_format($amount, 2, '.', '');

Good Luck!

Comment: It gave me a result of 115.00 instead of 0.115 how can I make it into 0.115 ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try:

```
number_format((float)'0.'$_POST['amount'], 2, '.', '');

decbin(number_format((float)'0.'$_POST['amount'], 2, '.', ''));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is my first time asking/posting a question here in stackoverflow. I usually post it on FB but no friends are replying at the moment. haha..